# Why does handling the tool tip role cause my entry not to show in my combo box?

Tags: qt, model, qcombobox

I'm handling tool tips for some items in my model, but the ones with tool tips are hidden/absent in my combo box drop-down.  Here is the `data` function of the model I'm using in my combo box:

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, const int role) const
{
   const DataStruct& data = m_data[index.row()];
   switch (role)
   {
      case Qt::DisplayRole:
         return data.name;

      case Qt::EditRole:
      case Qt::UserRole:
         return QVariant::fromValue(data.value);

      case Qt::ToolTip:
         if (data.condition)
         {
            return tr("Tool tip text");
         }
         return {};

      default:
         return {};
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`case Qt::ToolTip:` should be `case Qt::ToolTipRole:`.

`Qt::ToolTip` matches `Qt::SizeHintRole` - and when QVariant("any test") is interpreted as a `QSize` it is `-1, -1` causing the combo box to not show it.